# remove split lines by index with same value from list

Tags: c#, split, duplicates, line, distinct

-from the list an example is 9120038560640 occurs twice or could be more than that.

-lines stored in List<.string> items = File.ReadAllLines(filepath).ToList();
-every line is split in semi colon.
-second index or [1] should compare to all of the lines and remove with found matched.

363193;9120038560640;7,11;9,99 <---- must be remove
363195;9120038560641;9,81;14,99
363194;9120038560640;9,81;14,99 <--- must be remove
363196;9120038560642;9,81;14,99
363197;9120038560643;9,81;14,99
....
..
.

btw. my file has 25,000++ items.
thank you

Comment: Is this something you're having a problem with or are you just trying to get us to do it for you?

Comment: CSV to DataTable, Distinct by column, Save it again in file if it is needed. Also your question is too broad !

Comment: hi @Abion47 this is a bit tricky problem for me, so i am asking someone could help me.

Comment: hi @mybirthname is that using excel right? i already did that way. but i need to automate it.

Answer (score 0):

okay i got the answer and this is working

items = items.Where(x => x.Split(';')[columnIndex] != "").OrderBy(x => x.Split(';')[columnIndex]).ToList();
            List<.string> _items = items.ConvertAll(z => z); //I make independent copy

```
        string[] itemsArr = items.ToArray();
        int countA = 0;
        foreach (string itemArr in itemsArr)
        {
            List<int> groupDuplicates = new List<int>();
            for (int a = countA; a < itemsArr.Count(); a++)
            {
                if (itemArr != itemsArr[a])
                {
                    if (itemArr.Split(';')[columnIndex] == itemsArr[a].Split(';')[columnIndex]) //if matched then add
                    {
                        groupDuplicates.Add(a); // listing index to be remove
                    }

                    else
                        break; //no way to go through the bottom of the list and also to make the performance faster
                }
                countA++;
            }

            if (groupDuplicates.Count() != 0)
            {
                groupDuplicates.Add(groupDuplicates.First() - 1); //I add here the first item in duplicates

                foreach (int m in groupDuplicates)
                {
                    _items.Remove(items.ElementAt(m)); //remove by item not by index
                }
            }
        }
```